# Check if username exists not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I'm using this code to check if a username exists in a database.

```
  $sql = $db->query("SELECT FROM people (username, password, email) WHERE username=$username");


 if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
   {
    echo"name already exists";
   }
 else
    {
    $sqll = $db->query("INSERT INTO people (username, password, created, ip) VALUES ('{$username}','{$ph}',NOW(),'{$ip}' )") or die("Error creating user");

    }
```

But when I run it I get

> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Users/idrisk/Desktop/localhost/r.php on line 17

I'm not really sure what I should do. Is there a better way to check if the username exists?

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740) and make changes before continuing too far. (Also, *why* are you mixing `$db->*` and `mysql_*`? This seems questionable at best. And why are you calling the *result* "$sql"? It's not, the string contains the SQL.)

Comment: Should I do `$db->num_rows`? @user2864740

Comment: What is `$db`? (I didn't know mysql_ had an "OO" interface..)

Comment: My database connection... `$db = new mysqli('x','x','x','x')` @user2864740

Comment: *msqli_* is not *msql_*. Anyway, since you are using *mysqli* (not *mysql_*!), fix the query to use placeholders as per the link my first comment. Then, to check for a single row, simply try to read the row - don't check the count (which requires materialization). That is, simply do: `if ($sql->fetch()) { /* found a row! */ }`. But really, you should call $sql something else like $stmt to make the intent more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that warning because your mysql query syntax is wrong (it's expecting a mysqli_result object as response but recieves a boolean of `false`).

Change:

```
"SELECT FROM people (username, password, email) WHERE username=$username"
```

To:

```
"SELECT username FROM people WHERE username='$username'"
```

You don't need the select the password and email because you are just comparing the username. Selecting the password and email for no reason is just a waste on memory.

Comment: Works perfect, is this considered a safe way to do it?

Comment: @user302975 ofcourse, but as always, before executing any user input in a query, be sure to sanitize it with `mysql_real_escape_string()` or if using mysqli, then `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` for OOP way

Comment: So then this wouldn't work. `if($db->num_rows($sql)>=1){echo"name already exists";die(); }` How would I do it?

Comment: @user302975 The general idea is correct but currently your trying to get the rows from the `Mysqli` object, what you need to do is get the rows from the result object. So instead of `$db->num_rows($sql)` do `$sql->num_rows`. You can find out more info about `num_rows` at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
  $sql = $db->query("SELECT FROM people (username, password, email) WHERE username=$username");
```

to

```
  $sql = $db->query("SELECT username, password, email FROM people  WHERE username= '$username' ");
```

you have to select columns from table.